# Yosemite and FCP7? Compatability?

Tags: macos, final-cut-pro

I wanted to know, how compatible is FCP7 with Yosemite? FCP7 is the mainstay of my business and wanted to know if I should upgrade.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Final Cut Pro 7 does work on OS X Yosemite.

Check out ProVideoCoalition's post that detailing the installation of FCP7 on OS X 10.10; [Installing and editing with Final Cut Pro 7 on a new Macbook Pro with Yosemite](https://www.provideocoalition.com/installing-and-editing-with-final-cut-pro-7-on-a-new-macbook-pro-with-yosemite/)

> Overall the edit went very well. Not a crash, not a peep from Final
>   Cut Pro 7.0.3.
>
> Oh, and that was running Yosemite version 10.10 so we know Final Cut
>   Pro Classic is still working on Apple’s latest operating system.

Multiple users on [Apple Support Communities](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6614086) have said the same;

> **cameradude2**
>
> Does anyone know if Final Cut Pro 7 work in the new Yosemite upgrade?
>
> **Mer the Dog**
>
> It does on my system...

Answer (score 0):

RoaringApps might be the place to look.

This is the FCP7 page - http://roaringapps.com/app/final-cut-pro-7

Not enough reports to be truly certain as yet, I'd say.

I'd wait for at least 10.10.1 before moving mission-critical machines to it. I'm in pro-audio & I'm letting others iron out all the bugs before I make the leap.